# Rewrite query and tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have these below queries. Could you please review and let me know if the logic needs any modifications to better the performance. Please also suggest on indexes based on the logic (will crossverify and add if there are any missing)

Query (1)

```
SELECT DT.classid, 
       SUM(IT.expectedamount) AS expAmt, 
       SUM(IT.debitamount)    AS debAmt 
FROM   deptrans DT 
       inner join itemtotal IT 
               ON DT.id = IT.deposittransid 
       left outer join depreceipt DR 
                    ON DR.deposittransid = DT.id 
WHERE  DT.bankaccountid IN ( ? ) 
       AND (( ( DT.statecode IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                                  ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
                 OR ( DT.statecode IN ( ? ) 
                      AND IT.statecode = ? ) ) 
              AND DR.requesttime >= ? 
              AND DR.requesttime <= ? )) 
GROUP  BY DT.classid 
ORDER  BY DT.classid
```

[image: Query Execution Plan]

Query (2)

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT DT.id) 
FROM   deptrans DT 
       inner join itemtotal IT 
               ON DT.id = IT.deposittransid 
       left outer join depreceipt DR 
                    ON DR.deposittransid = DT.id 
WHERE  DT.bankaccountid IN ( ? ) 
       AND (( ( DT.statecode IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, 
                                  ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
                 OR ( DT.statecode IN ( ? ) 
                      AND IT.statecode = ? ) ) 
              AND DR.requesttime >= ? 
              AND DR.requesttime <= ? ))
```

[image: Query Execution Plan]

Indexes on the 3 tables (ITEMTOTAL IT,DEPTRANS DT and DEPRECEIPT DR ...resp) from above queries,

```
IX1_ITEMTOTAL                   ID
IX2_ITEMTOTAL   DEPOSITTRANSID
IX3_ITEMTOTAL   USERID
IX4_ITEMTOTAL   USERID, STATECODE

IX1_DEPTRANS    ID
IX2_DEPTRANS    CUSTOMERID
IX3_DEPTRANS    LOCATIONID
IX4_DEPTRANS    BANKACCOUNTID
IX5_DEPTRANS    STATECODE
IX6_DEPTRANS    TIMEZONEID
IX7_DEPTRANS    LASTMODIFYDATE, RESOURCENAME
IX8_DEPTRANS    AUTOCLOSESTATE
I035451031300_DEPTRANS_CDT_DNO  CREATEDATE, DEPOSITNUMBER
I035938031400_DEPTRANS_RCPTRNO  RECEIPTREFNUMBER

IX1_DEPRECEIPT  ID
IX2_DEPRECEIPT  DEPOSITTRANSID
IX3_DEPRECEIPT  USERID, REQUESTTIME, DEPOSITTRANSID
I035451031300_DEPRECP_PDATE POSTINGTIME
```

Comment: query plan is needed. consider posting this query in the https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Tables definition would also help.

Comment: please find the included query plans for both the sum and count queries

Comment: Plans of both queries show, that there is only 1 - or at most 14 records picked from tables - this is very little. Both queries use indexes, should be very fast, I don't see a reson to optimizethem further.

Comment: In general are the nested loops fine, or should we need to rule them out ?